# ASP Listbox 1 Column if selected gets the column value and another column from Datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use Listbox with the Ajax extender for autofill search. The Listbox is connected to a SQL datasource with 2 Columns, I know that Listbox doesn't support multicolumn. I am not interested in displaying the two columns what I am trying to do is as the following:

So far I have no problem in retrieving the 1st column value

```
string SupplierListtxt = SupplierListBox.SelectedItem.Text;
   MessageBox.Show(SupplierListtxt.ToString());
```

The concept is as the following:

Supplier Database has company names and a unique ID(SupplierID) set as Primary Key. Product Database has a SupplierID set as a foreign key.

So I want when the user selects the Listbox I should receive both info, the Company Name and SupplierID in order to INSERT it in to the Product Database.

Comment: MeesageBox in ASP.NET ? Use the debugger instead.

Comment: Still getting used to the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `DataTextField` **and** [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) before you DataBind the ListBox.

```
SupplierListBox.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
SupplierListBox.DataTextField="YourTextField";
SupplierListBox.DataValueField="YourIdField";
SupplierListBox.DataBind();
```

You get the value e.g. via `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem.Value`.

If you want to add the items programmatically you can add `ListItems`:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string id = i.ToString();
    string text = "Foo#" + i;
    SupplierListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, id));
}
```

Comment: Chief! you have fixed my problem. Thank you very much!